# Creating Specific Child While Messages Are Retrieving Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, parent-child

I am trying to make a message section in my app.

****Model Description:****

- You can ignore DUYURU, it isn't related with topic.
- child of *DUYURU* means author's **uid**.
- Number represents messages unique index.

---

### Model

[image: This is my Model]

### My java-android code:

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tests").child("DUYURU");
mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            posts.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot userMessages:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                //These 2 values become null since childs are not exist
                String sender = userMessages.child("sender").getValue(String.class);
                String photoUri = userMessages.child("photoUri").getValue(String.class);

                String uid = userMessages.getKey();

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: userMessages.getChildren()) {

                    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    post.setPostInfo(sender,photoUri,uid);
                    post.setIndex(Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.getKey()));
                    posts.add(post);

                }
            }

            Collections.sort(posts,Collections.<Post>reverseOrder());

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled: ",error.toException() );
        }
});
```

Then sender's value becomes null since there is no child called sender.

So how can i create a child if not exists while messages are retrieving.

Comment: Ideally if this is message it should have sender. If not, can't you just ignore it or have some default value for such messages.

Comment: I checked if child is not exist. I posted here

Answer (score 0):

```
//checking if object is not exist in for loop
if (!userMessages.hasChild("sender")) {                   
    mRef.child(userMessages.getKey()).child("sender").setValue("sendername");
}
```